# Syncing from windows time remove after reboot (NEED HELP)

Tags: windows, time, synchronization, clock

My problem is that at every restart the clock of my computer is 2hours before the hour is must be (just see in the atachements)
https://www.mediafire.com/file/be538o86dvre22w/Vid%25C3%25A9o_sans_titre.mp4/file
sorry for the mediafire, have no choice
sorry for my bad english and have a good day!

-Tried to change time in the bios